# Proof that posterior median is the Bayes estimate of absolute loss?

Tags: bayesian, estimation, median, point-estimation, absolute-risk

It is always argued that the posterior median is the Bayes estimate associated to the absolute loss function. The proofs I have come across rely on differentiating the conditional Bayesian risk and equating this to zero. However, this shows that this is an inflection point, but not that it is a minimum. How can one prove that the posterior median indeed minimizes the Bayesian risk?

[image]

Most, if not all, textbooks just go next level and just leave it as an exercise to the poor reader.

Comment: this is not an answer, but rather a request. could you please share the reference from where the image was taken? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Relevant (a proof that does not use differentiation): https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/600225/equivalent-of-ea-x2-ea-ex2-varx-for-ea-x-and-medx/600231#600231

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Second derivative yields

$$2  \pi (\delta | x) \geq 0$$

So the original function is convex and hence the median corresponds to a minimum not an inflection point

Comment: How do you get Zero? Are you using $d/dx \int_a^x f(y)dy =f(x)$ and $. - \int_x^a f(y)dy = \int_a^x f(y)dy $?

Comment: The second derivative as a function of $\delta$ is not zero everywhere. The first derivative is $ 2 \int^\delta \pi(y)dy - 1$. Taking the derivative a second time gives the above result which is clearly not zero everywhere

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Xiaomi answer, here is the derivation, using [Leibnitz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule):

$\require{cancel} 
\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial \delta} = \int_{-\infty}^{\delta}\pi(\theta|x)d\theta - \int_{\delta}^{\infty}\pi(\theta|x)d\theta \\
\frac{\partial^2 \rho}{\partial \delta^2} = \pi(\delta|x)\cdot1 - \cancel{\pi(\delta|x)\cdot0} + \cancel{\int_{-\infty}^{\delta}0d\theta} - [\cancel{\pi(\delta|x)\cdot0} - \pi(\delta|x)\cdot1 + \cancel{\int_{\delta}^{\infty}0d\theta}] = 2\pi(\delta|x)
$